# Crashlytics is logging crashes with the wrong line number

Tags: android, android-studio, crashlytics-android

I've been receiving a number of crash reports from a number of users on different devices, all happening on line 4 of my app:

[image]
[image]
[image]

But line 4 is just an import:

[image]

I'm running Android Studio 3.6.1 on a Linux laptop.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was not in Firebase but in R8 minifying. As pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64925782/9317258) try to add `-keepattributes LineNumberTable,SourceFile` to your `proguard.pro` file. It should help.

Comment: seems logical, as the line number is modified, which could be due to this.
I am also getting wrong number.

Answer (score 0):

Vít Kapitola's answer is not enough for my problem. In addition;
Add your `-keepattributes LineNumberTable,SourceFile` and `-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile` to your `proguard.pro` file.

For more information:
https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code#retracing